# Django: after submiting POST data page opens at a given div id, not at the top of the page

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a quite long and complicated form which has several submit buttons. When the user clicks a submit button their data is saved but then they are sent back to the top of the page, which is annoying because the user then has to scroll back down to get to the part of the form they were working on.

(The form controls the color and layout of the user's webpage, so the expectation is that the user will make many changes, submitting many times, rather than just filling out the form and submitting once.)

Is there any way to send the user to the correct part of the page (preferably without resorting to Javascript)?

Answer (score 2):

Create an anchor in your page at the correct location:

```
<a name="section1">Section 1</a>
```

Then use Django's [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) and with the anchor specified.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/form#section1')
```

Haven't tested this myself, but I'm assuming it will work because I've seen a few snippets like [this one](https://gist.github.com/617040).

Comment: In fact you don't even need an `<a>` tag - anything with an `id` attribute works as an anchor.

Comment: Thanks, that _almost_ works, but a redirect gives a GET request and I need to send my POST data back to the form (not all the POST data is saved to the database). I think I'm just going to have to grit my teeth and resort to Javascript here.